# Print or Display PHP array in Browser Console or in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i need to print php array in browser console using javascript

here i shared my code

```
<?php
function browser_console($data) {
    echo "<script>console.log('" . $data . "');</script>";
}
```

if anybody knows best code let me know .

thank you

Comment: not on click ... when page loads it should print..

Comment: You should state the problem clearly - I assume in this case you simply could not get it to work and saw nothing.

Comment: Who is executing browser_console?

Comment: i got it , thank you guys...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try using `json_encode()`

Example

```
echo "<script>console.log('" . json_encode($data) . "');</script>";
```

Comment: Be carefull, you pass the `$data` array as string.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in addition to what the others said - that way it gets `console.log`ged as an object, meaning you can expand it and navigate it in Chrome like so.

```
 echo "<script>console.log(JSON.parse('" . json_encode($data) . "'));</script>";
```

[image: screenshot of expanded object echoed like above]

**Source**: https://alligator.io/js/json-parse-stringify/

---

*Note*: I understand this question is asking about arrays, so string is probably fine, but to represent more complex objects this works better.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using

```
echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode(var_export($object, true)).");</script>";
```

as it allows you to display complex PHP objects and not only up to arrays.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to parse the array in json and be able to read it from javascript :

PHP file :

```
<?php 

$data = array(
    "data" => "Hello",
    "data1" => "World"
);

echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($data).");</script>";
```

Output in Web Console :

> Object { data: "Hello", data1: "World" }

Comment: @Kavin. Glad to hear it but this solution is different. Here you can use the json object from javascript. In the accepted solution, the json object is passed to javascript as a string.